# Akka: custom HttpHeader, convert HashMap to Iterable<HttpHeader> in java

Tags: java, http-headers, akka, akka-http, iterable

I'm trying to generate custom HttpHeader in akka. I've a HashMap of header entries which I need to convert to Iterable.
Here's my code:

```
import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpHeader;
HashMap<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
headersMap.put("key1","value1");
return (Iterable<HttpHeader>) headersMap;
//HttpRequest.create().withUri("uri").addHeaders(Iterable<HttpHeader> iterable)
public static Iterable<HttpHeader> convertToRecordHttpHeaders(Map<String, String> headersMap){
    return headersMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(x -> new HttpHeader(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

What's the efficient way to convert the map to HttpHeader and convert it to Iterable as I want to create a HttpRequest in akka.

Solution:
Used RawHeader to add headers to request

```
request.addHeader(RawHeader.create("key","value"));
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and clarify which library you are using (from where `HttpRequest` or `HttpHeader` comes from)?

Comment: I'm using import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpHeader;
getting an exception 'HttpHeader' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` is not an `Iterable` anything. Its `entrySet()`, `keySet()` and `values()` are, but for your map those are `Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>>`, `Iterable<String>` and `Iterable<String>` respectively. That means that you cannot cast the map in any way to an `Iterable<HttpHeader>`.

What you can do is convert:

```
List<HttpHeader> headersList = headersMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new HttpHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or just toList() with Java 17
```

This assumes that `HttpHeader` has a constructor that takes a header name and value. If it doesn't, replace the constructor call with something else that creates an `HttpHeader`.

Comment: I tried this to generate an Iterable for HttpHeader, getting an exception 'HttpHeader' is abstract; cannot be instantiated.

Comment: So my assumption doesn't hold. Check the documentation to see if there are sub classes, or otherwise a factory method.

Comment: I've seen your other comment and checked out https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-http/current/akka/http/javadsl/model/HttpHeader.html. You can use `HttpHeader.parse(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your Header class is something like this

```
class HttpHeader{
    public HttpHeader(Map.Entry<String,String> header){}
}
```

then just use constructor reference in place of lambda or else you  can provide your parsing using lambda expression

`headersMap.entrySet().stream().map(HttpHeader::new).iterator();`

But still i don't understand the use case of creating HashMap for return HttpHeader iterator.

i guess you used to keep header keys unique viva map however you can use TreeSet that will maintain unique objects too

```
class HttpHeader implements Comparable<HttpHeader>{
    String key;
    String value;
    
    public HttpHeader(String key, String value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HttpHeader o) {
        return key.compareTo(o.key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `iterator()` on the stream returns an `Iterator<HttpHeader>`, not an `Iterable<HttpHeader>`. The latter is a functional interface that has a single `iterator()` method. You also can't use `::iterator` on the stream because you can only call any terminal operator once.